# Can anyone please help me to explain this sentence "I think going only one day would be plenty.'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I am a ESL student. I have just been in US about one year.

Sometime i got stuck when I communicate with me classmates in class. I texted my classmate to invited her go to an event at school with me, but i did not get her meaning from her text.

Can anyone please help me to explain this sentence?

> I think going only one day would be plenty

What does she mean? Does she want to go with me or not?

Thanks for helping me and forgiving me with my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Winnie. Can you give us some more information about the situation? For example, does the event run over several days, or does it just happen on one day?

Comment: Agree with @JavaLatte, more info would be helpful. It sounds to me like this is for a music festival/conference/event that spans multiple days. Your friend thinks that going for just one of the days will be enough to get the full experience. (Yes, she wants to go with you)

Comment: The event will run on three days.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase pattern

> one *something* would be plenty

means one of *something* would be the same as having many (*plenty*) of something

when one has *plenty* of something, one is left without *wanting more*

It can have two different meanings that the speaker is saying the *one of something* is very rich and dense or they could be saying that it bores them and they don't really want that much of it, context is very important to figure out the really meaning. It depends if *one* is a little or alot.

> eating one banana split would be plenty
>   *after eating a banana split I will be full*
>
> one drink would be plenty
>   *after one drink I will be drunk*

In your original sentence, she might have used

> I think going *for* only one day, would be plenty
>   *I think going for only one day, would be enough*

She is basically saying to you that she only wants to go for one day and by setting her conditions out, if you're willing to abide by them, she wants to go with you.